# ANTLR4 JavaScript Target very slow

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, grammar, antlr4

I'm currently developing an ANTLR4 javascript listener for this [Grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java).

```
    var _require = require;
    var antlr = _require('./antlr4/index');
    var javaLexer = _require('./generated/JavaLexer');
    var javaParser = _require('./generated/JavaParser');
    var javaListener = _require('./generated/JavaListener');

    declare function require(name:string);

      class CodeAnalysis {

        input: String;

        constructor(input:String) {
          this.input = input;
          this.antlrStack();
        }

    private antlrStack() {
      console.log(this.input);
      var chars = new antlr.InputStream(this.input);
      var lexer = new javaLexer.JavaLexer(chars);
      var tokens = new antlr.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
      var parser = new javaParser.JavaParser(tokens);
      var listener = new javaListener.JavaListener();
      parser.buildParseTrees = true;
      var tree = parser.compilationUnit();


      antlr.tree.ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, tree);
    }

    public getInput() {
    return this.input;
    }


   }
```

The problem is that the performance is very bad (takes over two min) with an input like this:

```
import codescape.Dogbot;
public class MyDogbot extends Dogbot{

  public void run() {

    turnLeft();
    move();

  }
}
```

The same grammar and the same listener in Java performs a lot faster (>2 sec).

Anybody an idea why? Or how to fix it?

Bruno

Comment: I am also doing a JS target parser using ANTLR4. It is usually slow but it is not unbearably slow. What I do when I encounter an unbearable is modifying the grammar somehow and it usually improves the speed drastically.

Comment: facing same problem. Parsing through javascript antlr4 is much slower then java antlr4.